# Solving a reaction-diffusion problem using Separation of Variables

Tags: recreational-mathematics

$$U_{t} - D U_{xx}= -kU$$ where

BC: $U_{x}(0,t)=0$, $U_{x}(l,t)=0$

where

$0 < x < l$, $t > 0$

IC: $U(x,0)=A + B cos \big(\frac{2πx}{l}\big)$

where

$ 0<x<l$

where $D$ and $k$ are positive constants and $A$ and $B$ are constants.

I have been unable to find an example i can understand and apply to this problem.

Comment: Is $u\equiv u\left(x,t\right)$, or is that a typo? (i.e. was it meant to be an upper case $U$?)

Comment: Also, you mention constants $A,B$, but they never appear in your conditions.

Comment: I'm sorry i haven;t used latex in a really long time and i tried to copy and edit a post to make it easier and help me remember. It's fixed now

Comment: You should be able to do the separation of variables I.e $$U = X(x)T(t)$$

Can you put the rest together?

Comment: I know using that i would end up with $T'(t)/T(t) - D*X''(x)/X = -k$

(Also does Latex work in the comments or just in asking a question? I'm new to this site) Thank you.

Comment: Ah never mind it does work. Good i can type cleaner comments now.

Comment: Are you sure about the initial condition?

Comment: $U(x,0)=A + B cos (2πx/l)$. This is what i meant sorry

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. Suppose
$$
U\left(x,t\right)=X\left(x\right)T\left(t\right)
$$
with $X,T$ smooth. Substituting into the PDE,
$$
XT^{\prime}-DX^{\prime\prime}T=-kXT.
$$
Further suppose that $U\neq0$ so that dividing through by $XT$ yields
$$
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}+k=D\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}.
$$
Since the left-hand side depends only on $t$ and the right-hand side
depends only on $x$, this reveals that
$$
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}+k=\text{constant}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}=\text{constant}.
$$